# How to move image in the background of the view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image

I have a problem in my application i have a moving image it works fine.
But my image is also moving over a button, that i can't click when the image is before the button. How can i make sure that the image is moving on the background of my view so i can still press the button.

This is the code for the moving image

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self loadImage];
    image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cow.png"]];
    image.frame =self.view.bounds;
    [[self view] addSubview:image];


    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3
                                     target: self
                                   selector:@selector(moveImage:)
                                   userInfo: nil repeats:YES];



}



-(void) moveImage: (NSTimer*)timer {

    CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.width);
    CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.height);
CGPoint pointOne=CGPointMake(x,y);
    image.center=pointOne;
}
}
```

Comment: In first place I'd suggest rephrasing your question and improving its grammar, because as it's currently standing, it's hard to comprehend.

Comment: It's probably also a good idea to get your indentation settings altered.

Comment: I don't really understand the question? Please rephrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for a random index that isn't the current index, so that you can pick a random, different index, rather than just a random index.

```
- (NSUInteger)randomUnsignedLessThan:(NSInteger)max excluding:(NSUInteger)exclude {

    NSInteger firstTry = -1;
    while (firstTry == exclude) firstTry = arc4random() % max;
    return firstTry;
}
```

Note that this approach will always call arc4random once, and require 1+N calls with a probability of 1/max^N, so for low ranges, and high performance requirements, you might consider a different algorithm to exclude the one index.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in the fact that `arc4random_uniform()` calls take an upper bounds, not a 0-based count of args (as you, cleverly some would say, extrapolated).  Your equation is nearly-sound, however flawed in a few places, which I've tried to correct with some documentation:

```
-(void)someAction:(id)sender {
    NSInteger imageIndex1 = arc4random_uniform(self.images.count); //upper bounds, so no -1
    NSInteger imageIndex2 = arc4random_uniform(self.images.count); //upper bounds, so no -1
    NSInteger imageIndex3 = arc4random_uniform(self.images.count); //upper bounds, so no -1
    _Bool b1 = true, b2 = true, b3 = true; //I can only assume you've been declaring GNU C booleans because of the lowercase false.
                                              //be careful, in Objective-C land, BOOL is signed char.
    if (imageIndex1 == imageIndex2) {
        b1 = false;
        imageIndex2 = arc4random_uniform(self.images.count); //upper bounds, so no -1
    }
    if(imageIndex1 == imageIndex3) {
        b2 = false;
        imageIndex1 = arc4random_uniform(self.images.count); //upper bounds, so no -1
    }
    if (imageIndex2 == imageIndex3) {
        b3 = false;
        imageIndex3 = arc4random_uniform(self.images.count); //upper bounds, so no -1
    }
    //You have to use ors here, otherwise your UI will never actually update, considering that in checking
    //for unique factors, then reassigning to another unique factor if a check fails, one of them has got
    //to be true before the UI can update, rather than all 3 at once.
    //Perhaps an individual check of each boolean would be more effective.
    if(b1 == true || b2 == true || b3 == true ) {
        [self.picture1 setImage:self.images[imageIndex1]];
        [self.picture2 setImage:self.images[imageIndex2]];
        [self.picture3 setImage:self.images[imageIndex3]];
    }
}
```